# I'm trying to simulate 3 LED's with 2 switches using systemc

Tags: c++, systemc

With 2 switches s1,s2 and 3 Lights l1 l2 l3. pressing s1 or s2 should switch on l1. Next step if I press s1, l1(off) and l2(on) or if I press s2, l1(off) and l3(on). Final state is on press of any switch the light which is on will be off and we are in initial state.

```
#include <systemc>
using namespace sc_core;

SC_MODULE(lights_on)
{
    sc_in<bool> switch_1, switch_2;
    sc_out<bool> light_l1, light_l2, light_l3;
    
  void switch_on(){
    while(true) {
        if(switch_1.read() || switch_2.read())
        {
            light_l1.write(1);
            if(switch_1.read()){
                light_l1.write(true);
                light_l2.write(false);
        }
        if(switch_2.read())
        {
            light_l1.write(true);
            light_l3.write(false); 
        }

    }
  }
  }
      SC_CTOR(lights_on)
    {
        light_l1.initialize(true);
        light_l2.initialize(true);
        light_l3.initialize(true);
        SC_METHOD(switch_on);
        sensitive << switch_1 << switch_2;
    }
};

int sc_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  lights_on lights("lights_on");
  sc_start();
  return 0; 
 }
```

below error is seen

```
g++ -o sim -lsystemc *.cpp  && echo "Compile done. Starting run..." && ./sim  
Compile done. Starting run...

Error: (E109) complete binding failed: port not bound: port 'lights_on.port_4' (sc_out)
In file: ../../../src/sysc/communication/sc_port.cpp:235
Exit code expected: 0, received: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to the ports not being connected to anything. The other issue is the `while` loop which will just block forever. If you want to use `while` loops you will need to use systemc threads but we don't need them here.

Below I have created a test harness and some signals to connect it to your module. I have chosen to use a clock to drive the harness, it is not required to use a clock to drive it, it's just what I chose.

I did not change the internal logic, just pasted it in without the `while` loop.

```
#include <systemc>
using namespace sc_core;

SC_MODULE(lights_on)
{
    sc_in<bool> switch_1, switch_2;
    sc_out<bool> light_l1, light_l2, light_l3;

    void switch_on(){

        if(switch_1.read() || switch_2.read()){
            light_l1.write(1);
        
            if(switch_1.read()){
                light_l1.write(true);
                light_l2.write(false);
            }
            if(switch_2.read()){
                light_l1.write(true);
                light_l3.write(false); 
            }

       }
    }
    SC_CTOR(lights_on){
        light_l1.initialize(true);
        light_l2.initialize(true);
        light_l3.initialize(true);
        SC_METHOD(switch_on);
        sensitive << switch_1 << switch_2;
    }
};

SC_MODULE(test_harness){
    sc_out<bool> sw1, sw2;
    sc_in<bool> l1, l2, l3, clk;
    

    SC_CTOR(test_harness){
    SC_METHOD(proc);
    sensitive << clk.pos();     
}

void proc(void){

    bool s1 = (value & 1);
    bool s2 = (value & 2);
    sw1.write(s1);
    sw2.write(s2);
    value = (++value) % 4;
    
    std::cout << "s2 = " << s2 << ", s1 = " << s1 << '\n';  
    std::cout << "l1 = " << l1.read() << ", l2 = " << l2.read() << ", l3 = " << l3.read() << '\n';      
}

private:
    unsigned value = 0;
};

int sc_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    test_harness th("test_harness");
    lights_on ls("lights_on");  
    sc_clock clk("clk", 1.0, SC_SEC);

    // create some signals to connect up the ports
    sc_signal<bool> s1, s2, l1, l2, l3;

    // connect signals to test harness
    th.clk(clk);
    th.sw1(s1);
    th.sw2(s2);
    th.l1(l1);
    th.l2(l2);
    th.l3(l3);

    // connect signals to module under test
    ls.switch_1(s1);
    ls.switch_2(s2);
    ls.light_l1(l1);
    ls.light_l2(l2);
    ls.light_l3(l3);


    sc_start(10.0, SC_SEC); // run for 10 seconds

    return 0; 
 }
```

I compiled the above with `g++ -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp -lsystemc` and got the following output.

```
s2 = 0, s1 = 0
l1 = 1, l2 = 1, l3 = 1
s2 = 0, s1 = 1
l1 = 1, l2 = 1, l3 = 1
s2 = 1, s1 = 0
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 1
s2 = 1, s1 = 1
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
s2 = 0, s1 = 0
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
s2 = 0, s1 = 1
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
s2 = 1, s1 = 0
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
s2 = 1, s1 = 1
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
s2 = 0, s1 = 0
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
s2 = 0, s1 = 1
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
s2 = 1, s1 = 0
l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0
```